# Pandas & Dataframe: ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to find a similar question, but still couldnt find the solution.

I am working on a dataframe with pandas.

The following code is nor working. It is only working for the first row on the dataframe. Already for the second row I am getting the error. as below. Maybe somebody sees the mistake and can help :)

```
census2=census_df[census_df["SUMLEV"]==50]
list=census2["CTYNAME"].tolist() 

max=0 

for county1 in list:
    countylist=[]
    df1=census2[census2["CTYNAME"]==county1]
    countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2010"].item())
    countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2011"].item())
    countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2012"].item())
    countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2013"].item())
    countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2014"].item())
    countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2015"].item())
    countylist.sort()
    difference=countylist[5]-countylist[0]
    if difference > max:
        max=difference
        maxcounty=county1

print(maxcounty)
print(max)



[54660, 55253, 55175, 55038, 55290, 55347]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-340aeaf28039> in <module>()
     12     countylist=[]
     13     df1=census2[census2["CTYNAME"]==county1]
---> 14     countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2010"].item())
     15     countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2011"].item())
     16     countylist.append(df1["POPESTIMATE2012"].item())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in item(self)
    829         """
    830         try:
--> 831             return self.values.item()
    832         except IndexError:
    833             # copy numpy's message here because Py26 raises an IndexError

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Comment: The `ValueError` when you are trying to do `df1["POPESTIMATE2015"].item()`, suggests that, `df1` has more than **one** row. In other words, there are multiple entries for `county1` in `census2`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. However in the variable county1 is only 1 value behind.
When I change county1 to a string, which is the same to the first value in the data frame, but when i change county1 to a string which is the same like the value in the second row, it is not working anymore.

Comment: That doesn't add up. Can you recheck for the duplicate test, with the code `(census2["CTYNAME"].value_counts() > 1).index.values`